# How do I solve this integral

Tags: integration, quantum-mechanics

How do I solve this integral (expectation value) :
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi (x)^* \hat p \psi (x)\,\text{d}x.$$
where the $\hat p =-i\hbar \frac {\partial}{\partial x}$ is an operator and $\psi (x)$ is the wave function.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Chris Gerig exactly here $\langle \hat p \rangle$

Comment: Just a note: one *solves* equations and *evaluates* integrals.

Comment: You can't solve this and can't evaluate this integral unless wave function is not specified. In fact you are asking a regular method of evaluation average pulse for all possible wave functions, i.e.  for all possible quantum systems!